# Scatter and Hist in one subplot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

Here is code

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
    plt.subplot(121)
    df["a"].plot.box()
    plt.subplot(122)
    df.plot.scatter(x="a", y="b")
    plt.show()
```

Output comes in two different windows as follows:-

Figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2
[image: Figure 2]

Although both should come in one window. Any advice where is mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify which axis to draw on when you call `scatter`. This can be done by passing an `ax =` argument to the plotting function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
plt.subplot(121)
df["a"].plot.box()
ax = plt.subplot(122)
df.plot.scatter(x="a", y="b", ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: hats off to you